# Operator overloading leads to incorrect results

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have a Vector3 class that has + and * operators overloaded as follows:

```
Vector3& operator+ (Vector3& v1, Vector3& v2)
{
    Vector3 sum = Vector3(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z);
    static Vector3& ref = sum;
    return ref;
}

Vector3& operator* (Vector3& v1, double value)
{
    Vector3 product = Vector3(v1.x * value, v1.y * value, v1.z * value);
    static Vector3& ref = product;
    return ref;
}

Vector3& operator* (double value, Vector3& v1)
{
    Vector3 product = Vector3(v1.x * value, v1.y * value, v1.z * value);
    static Vector3& ref = product;
    return ref;
}
```

But when calculating a linear combination of 2 vectors v1 and v2, I get 2 different results when done separately vs in one line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector3.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Vector3 v1 = Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    Vector3 v2 = Vector3(2, 2, 2);

    Vector3 v3 = v1 * -1;
    Vector3 v4 = v2 * 1.2;

    cout << v3 + v4 << endl;

    cout << (v1 * -1.0) + (v2 * 1.2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(1.4, 0.4, -0.6)
(-2, -4, -6)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), anything is possible. The reference `ref` and returned reference refer to local object `sum` and `product`, which will be destroyed when get out of the function, left the returned reference dangling. Dereference on them leads to UB.

`operator+` and `operator*` are supposed to return by-value.

```
Vector3 operator+ (const Vector3& v1, const Vector3& v2)
{
    return Vector3(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z);
}

Vector3 operator* (const Vector3& v1, double value)
{
    return Vector3(v1.x * value, v1.y * value, v1.z * value);
}

Vector3 operator* (double value, const Vector3& v1)
{
    return Vector3(v1.x * value, v1.y * value, v1.z * value);
    // or 
    // return v1 * value;
}
```

BTW: I changed the operators taking `Vector3` as reference to `const`, which works with temporaries too.

Comment: I did actually implement it this way initially, however that leads to the problem that chaining operations leads to a really nasty error message that cant even comprehend. For example this line: cout << (v1 * -1.0) + (v2 * 1.2) << endl; causes an error.

Comment: @StealthyPanda Most likely because your versions of the operators take the arguments by non-const reference, which is also wrong.